# sql server creates unneeded rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The problem I have, is that if I run this query:

```
select 
    l.SiteID, 
    coalesce(sum(case when a.[TypeKey] = 1 then a.Calc else 0 end) /
nullif(case when TypeKey = 1 then count(l.LocationType) else 0 end, 0), 0) as 'My Type 1 avg',
    coalesce(sum(case when a.[TypeKey] = 2 then a.Calc else 0 end) /
nullif(case when TypeKey = 2 then count(l.LocationType) else 0 end, 0), 0) as 'My Type 2 avg'
from
    @NumberOfPeople a
inner join 
    Dim.Locations l on a.LocationType = l.LocationType
group by
    SiteID, TypeKey
```

Whenever it finds the second type of record, it creates a new row instead of placing the number into both of the Type average columns that I've created.

What its returning is this:

```
|SiteID|My Type 1 avg|My Type 2 avg| 
|1     |1.0          |0            | 
|2     |1.5          |0            | 
|3     |2.5          |0            |
|1     |0.0          |          1.5|
```

The result I want to see out of this query:

```
|SiteID|My Type 1 avg|My Type 2 avg| 
|1     |1.0          |          1.5| 
|2     |1.5          |0            | 
|3     |2.5          |0            |
```

I guess the problem is in Group By TypeKey is what causes this behaviour? And yet I can't just remove it due to the rules - as it then complains that its not part of that group by :

```
TypeKey is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
;WITH grouptable(
select l.SiteID, 
coalesce(sum(case when a.[TypeKey] = 1 then a.Calc else 0 end) /
nullif(case when TypeKey = 1 then count(l.LocationType) else 0 end, 0), 0) as 'My Type 1 avg',

coalesce(sum(case when a.[TypeKey] = 2 then a.Calc else 0 end) /
nullif(case when TypeKey = 2 then count(l.LocationType) else 0 end, 0), 0) as 'My Type 2 avg'
from
@NumberOfPeople a
inner join Dim.Locations l
on a.LocationType = l.LocationType
group by
SiteID,
TypeKey
)
SELECT SiteID,SUM([My Type 1 avg]) [My Type 1 avg],SUM([My Type 2 avg]) [My Type 2 avg]
FROM grouptable
GROUP BY SiteID
```

Comment: Column 'grouptable.My Type 1 avg' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.